# How to draw a text of several lines framed with tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am drawing a diagram with `tikzpicture`. The main idea is to draw several boxes of texts framed, and link them with lines...

What I know is using `\filldraw` to draw boxes, `\node` to write one line of text, and `\draw` to make a line. But I have to adjust every coordinator of every element... So my question is:

1) Is it possible to write a text of several lines?

2) Is it possible to frame a text of serveral lines?

Could anyone help? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `\node` can contain several lines of text; you can use the `align=` key and manually change lines with `\\`, or you can specify a width for the text:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[draw,align=center] (A) at (0,0) {some\\ text \\ spanning \\ several \\ lines};
  \node[draw,align=center,text width=1.5cm] at (3,0) {some text spanning several lines};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]